# Filter array based property value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, parsing

I have a JSON file containing 13k objects. I need to get only the objects which have the events `{ name: "Submitted"}` property from it. events is an array of objects which contain multiple name properties. Here is a screenshot of how it looks:

```js
{
  "_id": "03c319a5-86d4-4ce6-ba19-1a50584cecb4",
  "_rev": "21-7cb67ebb46c485ff443995fc27bdd950",
  "doctype": "application",
  "events": [{
      "name": "change",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "change",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "submitted",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "edited",
      "time": 1532547503182
    }
  ]
}
```

This is how I get all the object inside the json file:

```
$.getJSON("export.json", function(data) {
  var data = [];
  var arrays = data;

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrays[i]);
  }
});
```

Now I need to push all the objects which have `events[name:submitted]` I get in `arrays[i]` into the `doc[]`. How can I filter the results?

Comment: Why not filter it from where it from (backend)? Im not sure if there is an impact if you loop thru 13k of objects.

Comment: @Eddie this looks like PouchDB. Since it is a JS library that uses the IndexedDB it can‘t be really filtered at the backend. But there is a query function in PouchDB which you should take a look at as it is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()`, checking each element in the `events` array to see if the `name` is equal to `submitted`:

```js
const object = {
  "_id": "03c319a5-86d4-4ce6-ba19-1a50584cecb4",
  "_rev": "21-7cb67ebb46c485ff443995fc27bdd950",
  "doctype": "application",
  "events": [{
      "name": "change",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "change",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "submitted",
      "time": 1532547503182
    },
    {
      "name": "edited",
      "time": 1532547503182
    }
  ]
}

const filtered  = object.events.filter(obj => obj.name === 'submitted')
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your array of the object by `filter` method.

```
$.getJSON("export.json", function(data) {
  var data = [];
  var arrays = data;

  var newArray = arrays.filter(function (el) {
    return el.name == 'Submitted';
  });

  console.log(newArray);
});
```

You can also do in one line using `ES6 arrow function`

```
var newArray  = arrays.filter(el => el.name === 'Submitted')
```